# Jquery autocomplete from database with Spring Boot

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a search box and I would like it to show suggested keywords based on the users' typed input. I am using Jquery and spring boot. Here is the source code:

Backend Spring Boot:

```
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add("Aby");
    items.add("lop");
    items.add("eby");
    items.add("javay");
    items.add("issmail");
    items.add("sabou");
    items.add("query");
    items.add("napian");
    items.add("vira");
    items.add("rapi");

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonList = gson.toJson(items);

    model.addAttribute("tagList", jsonList);
```

Jquery:

```
  $( function() {     
var availableTags = [[${tagList}]];
console.log("Showing tags" + availableTags );

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
```

} );

The #tags is the id of the search box. The issue here is I can console.log and see the tags on the console, but the search box does not dropdown anything. Alternatively, when I manually type an array list as `var availableTags = ["tagOne","tagTwo","tagThree"];`, it works just fine?

Any suggestions?

Comment: why the extra `[[` ? try `var availableTags = [${tagList}];`

Comment: Use only `var availableTags = ${tagList};` It would works fine. Tested from my side.

Comment: When I try either  `var availableTags = [${tagList}];` or  `var availableTags = ${tagList};` I get an  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` and the console.log does not print out anything ! When on the other hand I do  `var availableTags = [[${tagList}]];` the console printout my array from the backend but it does not automatically show on when I type something i the search box...